# Решето Эратосфена на js

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, строки, циклы

Дано число n (n > 1). Выведите строку, состоящую из простых чисел, меньших n. Воспользуйтесь решетом Эратосфена. Единицу не считаем простым числом. Какой самый удобный способ вывести в результате не массив, а строку (без методов можно?)?

```
var array = [], limit = Math.sqrt(n), result = [];

    // Создаю массив от 2 до (n - 1)
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        array.push(true);
    }

    // Удаляю кратные 2, 3, 5...
    for (var i = 2; i <= limit; i++) {
        if (array[i]) {
            for (var j = i * i; j < n; j += i) {
                array[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Все значения массива [i] true являются простыми числами
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if(array[i]) {
            result.push(i);
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

Comment: в конце `return result.join(“ ”)`

Comment: Спасибо! Правда, я хотела узнать, как без методов обойтись.

Comment: собирайте сразу строку

Comment: Научите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не нужно обходиться "без методов", когда они есть. Если в академических целях - реализуйте функцию join самостоятельно.

Comment: Какое-то неправильное решето...

Comment: Не хватает объявления функции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собирайте сразу строку

——-

```
var result = "";

...

if (array[i]) {
   result += " " + i
}

return result;
```

Comment: да нет проблем, обращайтесь

Comment: @1507-e можете выбрать его как правильный ответ ( галочка под рейтингом )

Comment: @ThisMan как мило с Вашей стороны, сейчас отомщу

Comment: Хорошо, готово)

Comment: `for (var i = 2;` - неправильно же.

Comment: @Qwertiy а ведь да, 2 и 3  цикл с 0 надо начинать

Comment: Неа, надо просто инициализацию заменить на `array = [false, false]`.

Comment: @Qwertiy да и изначально алгоритм я не понял да и не очень хотел, т.к. вопрос был про строку :)

Comment: А то при n=8 теряется семёрка.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну да, просто поменять индекс тут не получится без изменения тела цикла, в любом случае подправлю только когда доберусь до компа, на мобиле сниппеты редактировать и запускать жуткий гемор

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, да тут 2 варианта: поменять первый цикл с 2 на 0 или заполннить массив изначально как я написал выше. В обоих случаях заработает, но идейно вариант с false правильнее. Что именно поменять не получится, я не понял.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему я не могу создать массив начиная с 2, ведь единица не простое число(

Comment: @1507-e в массиве первый элемент соответствует какому числу?

Comment: А. Я так поняла, два последних цикла надо было с 0 начинать. Первый все равно не понимаю, почему с 2 нельзя.

Comment: @1507-e можно, просто Qwertiy предложил решение как не меняя индексы (с какого элемента) начинать Ваш код работал

Comment: Теперь разобралась, спасибо!

Comment: @1507-e нет проблем, обращайтесь

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95323/discussion-between-1507-e-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите получить строку без методов, реализуйте метод join самостоятельно:

```js
function primes(N) {
  let res = [2];
  for (let i = 3; i < N; i+=2) {
    let isPrime = true;
    for (let k = 0, limit = Math.sqrt(i); res[k] <= limit; ++k) {
      let d = res[k];
      if (i % d == 0) {isPrime = false;break;}
    }
    if (isPrime) res.push(i);
  }
  return res;
}

let res = primes(100);

// res.join(', ')
function list_join(list, sep = ',') {
  let str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    let el = list[i];
    str += el;
    if (i < list.length-1) str += sep;
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(res.length);
console.log(list_join(res, ', '));
```